# Custom post type with page and pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

How can I have the same page slug and custom post type. I have it now working with the option `has_archive` set to false. But when I want to implement pagination on this page, I get the 404 error on page 2. I have searched Stackoverflow allot but can't find any solution according to this.

Comment: have you refreshed the permalinks?

Comment: Yes multiple times..